# Keeping button div in static position as window is resized

Tags: html, css, resize

I am fairly new to css and html and so I am having a little trouble positioning divs that stay in that positioning when the window is resized.
If I could have any help in positioning a button I have on my website while keeping it static as the window is resized that would be great.

Here is the link: 
http://jsfiddle.net/aritro33/B8dLk/4/

Notice how the POST button moves around as the window is resized. How would I keep it stationary at the edge of the body?

Thanks!

HTML:

```
<div class = "header"><span class = "headert" contenteditable = "true">YOUR TITLE:</span></div>
<div class = "body"><span class = "bodyt" contenteditable = "true">And a little more explanation, please!</span></div>
<div class = "buttoncontainer"><a href="#" class="postbutton">Post</a></div>
```

CSS:

```
 @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400);


body{
    background-color: #268fd6;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.header{
    background-color: #144c72;
    height: 80px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-top-left-radius: 30px;
    border-top-right-radius: 30px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
}

.headert{
    font-family: 'Oswald';
    font-style: light;
    font-size: 50px;
    position: relative;
    left: 15px;
    top: 5px;
    color: white;
    outline: 0px solid transparent;
}

.body{
    background-color: #2980B9;
    min-height: 70px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
     overflow: hidden;
     padding: 20px;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;

}

.bodyt{
    color: white;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: 'Oswald';
    outline: 0px solid transparent;
    font-style: light;
}

.postbutton {
    background-color:#27AE60;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:6px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:6px;
    border-top-left-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:6px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:6px;
    border-top-right-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:6px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:6px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:6px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:6px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:6px;
    text-indent:0;
    border:1px solid #27AE60;
    display:inline-block;
    color: white;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:normal;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    width:100px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    position: relative;
    top: 60px;
    left: 66.5%;
}

.buttoncontainer{
   position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/B8dLk/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
.wrapper{
    width:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I like this answer, however, because of this solution, it would screw up the "margin: 0 auto" property on header and body which I don't want... @user3267592

Comment: Thank you! This was just the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Place that button within the div just above it, and then adjust the body to not hide the overflow.

```
<div class = "body"><span class = "bodyt" contenteditable = "true">And a little more explanation, please!</span>
  <div class = "buttoncontainer">
  <a href="#" class="postbutton">Post</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Once the button is contained within the parent body it will move and behave as part of that element. You will have to fiddle with the layout a bit for your design, but the general solution is here.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/B8dLk/11/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.buttoncontainer{
width: 500px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
}
```

It should fix it.

This is because the current div is having an auto margin and when you resize the window it changes the margin.